What does "No Reachable Authority at delegation" mean? (aka NS record not returned by the DNS)
I own a domain (further referred to as example.com), it is registered with OVH. It has a few A and MX records, all are served correctly by OVH's DNS servers.
I now want to delegate home.example.com to a home server (PiHole) on 192.168.10.2. This DNS server is live and serving many records correctly.
To delegate the subdomain, I added the following to the example.com DNS zone:
home           IN NS    ns-home.example.com.
ns-home        IN A     192.168.10.2

OVH automatically increments the zone serial. To make sure it is correct I checked it:
root@srv ~# dig @1.1.1.1 example.com SOA

example.com. 3600 IN SOA dns102.ovh.net. tech.ovh.net. 2024122001 86400 3600 3600000 60

2024122001 is what I also see in the DNS zone on OVH. So the new version of the zone has been deployed.
The problem: the A record is returned correctly, but the NS is not:
root@srv ~# dig @1.1.1.1 ns-home.example.com A
ns-home.example.com. 3600 IN A 192.168.10.2

dig @1.1.1.1 home.example.com NS
;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
; EDE: 22 (No Reachable Authority): (at delegation home.example.com.)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;home.example.com.               IN      NS

What does this answer mean? What else should be done to delegate the subdomain?

I will eventually move the NS record to the local name server with a glue record, for now I would like to have it working in this simpler scenario

The query you made for NS was recursive1; meaning that the response wouldn't come from the delegation records at OVH – it would in fact follow the delegation all the way and return the in-zone NS records from your PiHole.
But the delegation NS records point at a private IP address, 192.168.10.2, which CloudFlare's 1.1.1.1 resolver is unable to reach – so it will never be able to resolve anything behind that delegation, nor will any other public resolver. That's what the 2nd answer means; it means "1.1.1.1 could not contact 'ns-home.example.com'
at 192.168.10.2" (ns-home being the "authority").
Keep in mind: The server you specify using @ isn't just the "starting point" for dig; it is the server which does all the delegation chasing for you, whereas dig itself does nothing but wait for a response – which is exactly how your OS handles DNS queries, too.
Thus, it isn't enough for delegations to have A/AAAA records that are accessible from the client's perspective, they also have to be accessible from the resolver's perspective.
So if you're completely sure that the resolver will be internal to your own network (like, say, if your PCs all query your local PiHole, and the PiHole runs Unbound or BIND9 to locally chase delegations without relying on any upstream) – then sure, your current setup would work, but you should test it with dig @<pihole_ip> rather than dig @<random_public_resolver>.
However, if you want the delegated subdomain (and its sub-sub-domains) to be resolvable using any public server, then the delegation has to be made towards a publicly accessible IP address. You would have to check what DNS software the PiHole is running, whether it is suitable to be exposed to Internet (i.e. security assessment), set up "port forwarding" for TCP/53 and UDP/53 from your main LAN gateway to the PiHole (for IPv4), and finally change the ns-home A/AAAA to point to your public IPv4 address (and/or the PiHole's public IPv6).

1 The query had the 'Recursion Desired' option set, which is default for dig, and is also the only way you'd get a response from 1.1.1.1 or another resolver anyway.
Turning off this option can be done using +norecurse or +nordflag, but a non-recursive query has to be made directly against the authoritative servers – i.e. servers which themselves already hold the DNS data for your domain. And if you tell 'dig' to query at an authoritative server... then specifying +norecurse becomes kind of redundant.
So if you wanted to test specifically whether OVH published your NS record correctly, you would have to do:
dig [+norecurse] @nsXXX.ovh.net home.example.com NS

Alternatively, tools which can follow the delegation path:

dnstracer -s . home.example.com
delv [-i] +ns home.example.com(the -i suppresses DNSSEC validation for a more minimal output)
dig +trace home.example.com(might be less accurate)
DNSViz.


Thank you. The more I am thinking about it (also when reading your answer that is logical and I should have understood that before), the less it makes any sense. I will just use home.example.com in the internal network without any delegation - because it will never be queried from outside. The whole question does not make sense but I will keep it here in case someone has similar brilliant ideas :) Thanks again!

As an aside, some resolvers will filter out DNS responses which include RFC1918 addresses (for security reasons, I suppose). That's the case of the resolver in my ISP's box, for instance. Not an issue if you use four-ones or four-eights directly, but  it can be surprising...
